# "He made them to be the most understood" Vs."He made them be the most understood"

Tags: prepositions

I wrote the sentence about written exams:
**"He made them *to* be the most understood"**, but my automatic grammar corrector shows me that it's a mistake to add the preposition 'to' in this sentence, and it should be instead: **"He made them be the most understood"**.

To my eyes, as a non-native English speaker, it doesn't seem to be natural, but I'm afraid I'm wrong in that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither of these sound natural.

The difference between "he made them understood" and "he made them **to be** understood" is that the former means 'he' was directly responsible for ensuring others understood, whereas the latter means it was just his *intention* that others understand and made efforts to make the message understandable.

The problem with your examples is when you bring in the superlative "the most" - it doesn't seem appropriate in the context. You use a superlative in a comparative sense - something might be "the most understood" when compared to other things that are not so easily understandable.

I think what you mean to say is that 'he' deliberately made whatever it was understandable so that *most* people could understand it. You could express that by saying:

> He made them to be *easily understandable*.

or

> He made them to be *widely understood*.